# How to fix memory leak in NSMutableString?

Tags: memory, memory-leaks, nsmutablestring

when i check memory leak through instrument it shows leak on NSMutableString.Here is the leaked code ,

[image]

whats the 66.7% means..? How to solve this leak.?

Second method shown in call tree is

[image]

The createEnvelope method is shown first.

Comment: are you using ARC? If not, try changing `[NSMutableString new]` to `[[NSMutableString new] autorelease]`

Answer (score 0):

It is not a memory leak as such, but you are right, many string operations in memory, possibly causing a memory fragmentation, at least a bad memory behaviour, see `autorelease` too.

Use `stringWithCapacity` to initialize with sufficient space, so no reallocations occur.

Style issue: maybe use NSString here.